# Display Star Rating without voting

Tags: php

I am a little stuck.

I have a Mysql database with items. Each item already has a corresponding rating (0-5).

Now, when I display the list of items, I want to convert the rating in stars.
They may not be clickable.

But how can I display rating stars for each rating?

Like:

```
Item[1] Rating: 4 => display 4 stars
Item[2] Rating: 2 => display 2 stars
Item[3] Rating: 1 => display 1 star
and so on
```

I am calling the existing rating like this:

```
php echo $item['Item']['rating']
```

Comment: tried http://masugadesign.com/software/unobtrusive-ajax-star-rating-bar/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php):

```
print str_repeat('*', $item['Item']['rating']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $item['Item']['rating']; $i++) {
    echo '<img src="star.gif" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

echo str_repeat('*', $item['Item']['rating']);

it will print * as many times as ratings..